# Rearranging jquery Datatable format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using Datatables for my mvc project. I would like to know is there any possibility that I can rearrange some items without messing with datatable js file? Below is what I needed to rearrange.

[image]

I don't have any idea whether I can do that or not. Please guide.

Comment: You can. Have a look here =>  https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xft50ho5/200/) fiddle it might be helpful to moving controls of datatble jquery and for information to customize as you want please refer [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) link.

In fiddle i have change position and remove "Table information summary"

this is the trick that works behind this to understand how it works please refer [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) link

```
"dom": '<"top""row"<"col-sm-6"f>>rt<"bottom""row"<"col-sm-6"l>p><"clear">'
```